# Give effects to entities if they are standing on a specific block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to give mobs effects if they stand on a specific block (for example, if a sheep stands on grass, it gets regeneration) using this command:

```
/execute @e[type=Sheep] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ grass 0 effect @e[type=Sheep] regeneration 1 0
```

However, it targets all sheep, even if only one fulfills the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Use `c=1` so that the sheep successfully detecting the grass will only target itself:

```
/execute @e[type=Sheep] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 0 effect @e[type=Sheep,c=1] regeneration 1 0
```